# calculate quantile by group in Sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, group-by, quantile, sparklyr

I have a dataframe in Spark, and would like to calculate the 0.1 quantile after grouping by a specific column.

For example:

```r
> library(sparklyr)
> library(tidyverse)
> con = spark_connect(....)

> diamonds_sdl = copy_to(con, diamonds)
> diamonds
# Source:   table<diamonds> [?? x 10]
# Database: spark_connection
   carat cut       color clarity depth table price     x     y     z
   <dbl> <chr>     <chr> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 0.230 Ideal     E     SI2      61.5  55.0   326  3.95  3.98  2.43
 2 0.210 Premium   E     SI1      59.8  61.0   326  3.89  3.84  2.31
 3 0.230 Good      E     VS1      56.9  65.0   327  4.05  4.07  2.31
 4 0.290 Premium   I     VS2      62.4  58.0   334  4.20  4.23  2.63
 5 0.310 Good      J     SI2      63.3  58.0   335  4.34  4.35  2.75
 6 0.240 Very Good J     VVS2     62.8  57.0   336  3.94  3.96  2.48
 7 0.240 Very Good I     VVS1     62.3  57.0   336  3.95  3.98  2.47
 8 0.260 Very Good H     SI1      61.9  55.0   337  4.07  4.11  2.53
 9 0.220 Fair      E     VS2      65.1  61.0   337  3.87  3.78  2.49
10 0.230 Very Good H     VS1      59.4  61.0   338  4.00  4.05  2.39
```

My first thought was to use group_by and summarise, but apparently the quantile function is not implemented in sparklyr:

```
> diamonds_sdl %>% group_by(color) %>% summarise(q1=quantile(carat, .1))
Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Undefined function: 'QUANTILE'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'tsci
'.; line 1 pos 16
```

No luck using sdl_quantile, as suggested here: https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr/issues/204 . Note that I've just upgraded sparklyr, and running version 0.7.0-9004 from github.

```
> diamonds_sdl %>% group_by(color) %>% summarise(q1=sdf_quantile(carat, .1))
Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Undefined function: 'SDF_QUANTILE'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database '
tsci'.; line 1 pos 16
```

sdf_quantile works if I want to calculate the quantile on the whole column - but this is not what I am interested in:

```
> sdf_quantile(diamonds_sdl, "carat", 0.1)
 10%
0.31
```

I've tried to other approaches.

The first is to use spark_apply. However it seems that it doesn't work properly in my installation. Another run returned an error saying that "Rscript" was not installed in the node. However, I cannot really fix this problem as I do not have admin rights.

```
> spark_apply(diamonds_sdl, function(x) quantile(x, 0.1))
Error: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 35.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 35.0 (TID 735, myserver
.com, executor 393): java.lang.Exception: sparklyr worker rscript failure with status 255, check worker logs for details.
        at sparklyr.Rscript.init(rscript.scala:98)
        at sparklyr.WorkerRDD$$anon$2.run(rdd.scala:95)
```

The second approach was to use collect_list as in here: [Sparklyr: Use group_by and then concatenate strings from rows in a group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44399954/sparklyr-use-group-by-and-then-concatenate-strings-from-rows-in-a-group)

```r
# This one almost works
> diamonds_sdl %>% group_by(color) %>% summarise(q1=paste(collect_list(as.character(carat))))
# Source:   lazy query [?? x 2]
# Database: spark_connection
  color
  <chr>
1 F
2 E
3 D
4 J
5 G
6 I
7 H
  q1
  <chr>
1 0.22 0.23 0.23 0.23 0.23 0.29 0.24 0.26 0.7 0.96 0.81 0.8 0.73 0.73 0.8 0.8 …
2 0.23 0.21 0.23 0.22 0.2 0.32 0.23 0.23 0.23 0.23 0.25 0.22 0.24 0.26 0.26 0.…
3 0.23 0.23 0.26 0.26 0.26 0.22 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.24 0.26 0.26 0.26 0.75 0.71 0.61…
4 0.31 0.24 0.3 0.23 0.31 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.31 0.31 0.3 0.33 0.3 1.17 1.05 1.05 1.…
5 0.23 0.23 0.28 0.31 0.31 0.24 0.7 0.78 0.74 0.75 0.75 0.8 0.74 0.71 0.64 0.7…
6 0.29 0.24 0.3 0.3 0.24 0.33 0.33 0.32 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.35 0.42 0.32 0.38 0.…
# but here is the error
> diamonds_sdl %>% group_by(color) %>% summarise(q1=quantile(as.numeric(paste(collect_list(as.character(carat))))))
Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Undefined function: 'QUANTILE'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'tsci
'.; line 1 pos 16
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For grouped data your best bet is `percentile_approx`:

```
diamonds_sdl %>% group_by(color) %>% summarise(q1 = percentile_approx(carat, .1))
```

```
# Source:   lazy query [?? x 2]
# Database: spark_connection
  color    q1
  <chr> <dbl>
1 H     0.310
2 F     0.310
3 G     0.310
4 I     0.320
5 J     0.400
6 D     0.310
7 E     0.300
```

This however, required Spark, with Hive support enabled and is less efficient than built-in `approxQuantile`.

Comment: Thank you, but I get the error: Error in percentile_approx(carat, 0.1): could not find function "percentile_approx". Should I load other libraries? Not sure how to enable Hive support in Spark, and if I can do it without admin privileges.

Comment: In the end, I've created a table with the quantile summaries in Hive SQL and queried it from there.

Comment: Strange. What do you get when you call `sc %>% spark_session %>% invoke("conf") %>% invoke("get", "spark.sql.catalogImplementation")`?

Comment: it says just "hive"