# R SparkR - equivalent to melt function

Tags: r, apache-spark, reshape2, sparkr

Is there a function similar to `melt` in SparkR library?

Transform data with 1 row and 50 columns to 50 rows and 3 columns?

Comment: @sramalingam24 That's not even remotely true. In general utilities designed to work with `data.frame` are not compatible with `SparkDatafarme`.

Comment: @sramalingam24 Well, if you do that, data will be no longer distributed and likely crash your program (if using SparkR makes any sense in the first place). In general there is no efficient and scalable way to use arbitrary R function with SparkR data structures.

Answer (score 6):

There is no built-in function that provides a similar functionality in SparkR. You can built your own with `explode`

```
library(magrittr)

df <- createDataFrame(data.frame(
  A = c('a', 'b', 'c'),
  B = c(1, 3, 5),
  C = c(2, 4, 6)
))

melt <- function(df, id.vars, measure.vars, 
                 variable.name = "key", value.name = "value") {

   measure.vars.exploded <- purrr::map(
       measure.vars, function(c) list(lit(c), column(c))) %>% 
     purrr::flatten() %>% 
     (function(x) do.call(create_map, x)) %>% 
     explode()
   id.vars <- id.vars %>% purrr::map(column)

   do.call(select, c(df, id.vars, measure.vars.exploded)) %>%
     withColumnRenamed("key", variable.name) %>%
     withColumnRenamed("value", value.name)
}

melt(df, c("A"), c("B", "C")) %>% head()
```

```
  A key value                                                                   
1 a   B     1
2 a   C     2
3 b   B     3
4 b   C     4
5 c   B     5
6 c   C     6
```

or use SQL with Hive's `stack` UDF:

```
stack <- function(df, id.vars, measure.vars, 
                  variable.name = "key", value.name = "value") { 
  measure.vars.exploded <- glue::glue('"{measure.vars}", `{measure.vars}`') %>%  
    glue::glue_collapse(" , ") %>%
    (function(x) glue::glue(
      "stack({length(measure.vars)}, {x}) as ({variable.name}, {value.name})"
    )) %>%
    as.character()
    do.call(selectExpr, c(df, id.vars, measure.vars.exploded))
}

stack(df, c("A"), c("B", "C")) %>% head()
```

```
  A key value
1 a   B     1
2 a   C     2
3 b   B     3
4 b   C     4
5 c   B     5
6 c   C     6
```

Related questions:

- [Gather in sparklyr](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50465390/6910411)
- [How to melt Spark DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41670103/6910411)

Comment: very elegant solution. thanks! I think it can be further simplified by replacing
```id.vars <- id.vars %>% purrr::map(column)

   do.call(select, c(df, id.vars, measure.vars.exploded))```
with 
```df %>% select(c(id.vars, measure.vars.exploded))```
at least it worked on my version of RSpark (2.4)