# use DPLYR to add a new row as a calculation of other grouped rows

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data object similar to the following:

```
> temp2 %>% arrange(date_val) %>% select(date_val,kpi_name,kpi_value)
# Source:     spark<?> [?? x 3]
# Ordered by: date_val
   date_val     kpi_name              kpi_value
   <dttm>              <chr>                     <dbl>
 1 2018-12-04 00:00:00 KPI1                          0
 2 2018-12-04 00:00:00 KPI2                         38
 3 2018-12-04 00:01:00 KPI2                         55
 4 2018-12-04 00:01:00 KPI1                          1
 5 2018-12-04 00:02:00 KPI2                         55
 6 2018-12-04 00:02:00 KPI1                          1
 7 2018-12-04 00:03:00 KPI1                          0
 8 2018-12-04 00:03:00 KPI2                         58
 9 2018-12-04 00:04:00 KPI2                         45
10 2018-12-04 00:04:00 KPI1                          1
# â¦ with more rows
>
```

I would like to insert a new row for each grouped date_val which will perform a calculation for that date_val group on the kpi_name/kpi_value available in the current object. For example, let's say I need to calculate the following  new KPI3 as 100*(KPI1/KPI2) which will provide a new data object such as:

```
# Source:     spark<?> [?? x 3]
# Ordered by: date_val
   date_val     kpi_name              kpi_value
   <dttm>              <chr>                     <dbl>
 1 2018-12-04 00:00:00 KPI1                          0
 2 2018-12-04 00:00:00 KPI2                         38
 3 2018-12-04 00:00:00 KPI3                          0
 4 2018-12-04 00:01:00 KPI2                         55
 5 2018-12-04 00:01:00 KPI1                          1
 6 2018-12-04 00:01:00 KPI3                      0.018
 7 2018-12-04 00:02:00 KPI2                         55
 8 2018-12-04 00:02:00 KPI1                          1
 9 2018-12-04 00:02:00 KPI3                      0.018
10 2018-12-04 00:03:00 KPI1                          0
11 2018-12-04 00:03:00 KPI2                         58
12 2018-12-04 00:03:00 KPI3                          0
13 2018-12-04 00:04:00 KPI2                         45
14 2018-12-04 00:04:00 KPI1                          1
15 2018-12-04 00:04:00 KPI3                      0.022
# â¦ with more rows
```

Can this be done in DPLYR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
library(tidyverse)

temp2 %>% spread(kpi_name, kpi_value) %>% 
  mutate(KPI3 = 100*(KPI1/KPI2)) %>% 
  gather(kpi_name, kpi_value, -date_val)
```

While it's technically possible `rbind` in new rows, it's comparatively inefficient and syntactically clunky. It makes much more sense to transform to the logical wide format, add the column, and then transform back.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like the spark object does not support the spread function, but I can covert the object to "as_tibble" first and it works as expected.

Comment: @JeffKraus Great, also, this answer might help if you want to stay with the spark object: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50465390/gather-in-sparklyr